# Clickhouse server failed to restart because of LowCardinality setting

Tags: clickhouse

I tried to play with LowCardinality setting, I got a message saying that this is an experimental feature and I have to SET allow_experimental_low_cardinality_type = 1 in order to use it.

I executed this command inside clickhouse-client and then I restarted the server. But I got
clickhouse-server.service: Unit entered failed state

Now I am trying to find out how to disable this setting and make my clickhouse-server start again.
Can you help with this please ?

PS: The version I use is the 18.12.17 and I installed it on Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse has different layers for settings. If you used `SET <setting> = <value>` then you set it for current session. You don't need to restart ClickHouse. Please, take a look [here](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/).

I suppose you faced with another problem during starting your server. There a bunch of reasons why. So, firstly try to recollect what were done in configs since last restart (because you have just applied changes by restarting server).

Digging into logs also an awesome idea. Don't hesitate to check other similar issues on github.com, for example like [this one](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/1981)